# I want to register my first Admin to start working on the rest of the roles and I don't know what service is missing in my IServicecollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, .net-5

I am working with .NET 5 to build an online shop. My project is divided into 4 projects , {project'the main which includes the controllers', project.DataAccess , project.Models , project.Utility}  I am using RazorPages and Identity core package for the registeration and handling roles part. In the utility project I have class "SD" storing roles contains the following code,

```
 public static class SD
{
    public const string Role_User_Indi = "Individual Customer";
    public const string Role_User_Designer = "Designer Customer";
    public const string Role_Admin = "Admin";
    public const string Role_Moderator = "Moderator";
}


//now this is inside register.cshtml.cs in the identity folder inside the areas
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            { 
                UserName = Input.UserName,
                Email = Input.Email,
                DesignerShopId = Input.DesignerShopId,
                Role = Input.Role
            };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                //first check if the role is in the database
                if(!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(SD.Role_Admin))
                {
                    //if it doesn't exist it will create it 
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(SD.Role_Admin));
                }
                if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(SD.Role_Moderator))
                {
                    //if it doesn't exist it will create it 
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(SD.Role_Moderator));
                }
                if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(SD.Role_User_Indi))
                {
                    //if it doesn't exist it will create it 
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(SD.Role_User_Indi));
                }
                if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(SD.Role_User_Designer))
                {
                    //if it doesn't exist it will create it 
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(SD.Role_User_Designer));
                }
                //for now we will make anyone registers as an admin as default
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, SD.Role_Admin);
                /** var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    $"Please confirm your account by <a //href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>."); **/

                if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                }
                else
                {
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
```

I wanted to register my first admin through running the project and register on the website that's why I commented some of the PostOnSync to make anybody register for that moment an admin as You can see in the code and I changed in the start up class to inject Identity role with the default tokens As the following

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        //services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>().AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        //services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
          //  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddHealthChecks();

    }
```

It throughs a runtime exception that
Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddRazorPages' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)

What can I do to resolve this exception , Is there an other way to register my first admin? should I add it manually to the database table in sql mangement studio?  any better way to customize the package to handle roles as I want ?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to add the following line to you ConfigureServices() method ? :

**services.AddRazorPages();**

As you uses Razor for pages and rendering, you has to declare it in the service.

Hope it may fix your problem